# Can't install WordGrinder on Yosemite

Tags: macos, install, command-line, error, word-processor

Recently, I have been trying to install WordGrinder on Yosemite. First I tried getting the latest tar packages from the developers' website and using them, but I ran into some library linking errors with `lua` and `ncursesw`. I tried using MacPorts because I assumed that it would do all of that for me, but it turns out that the problems I encountered first were just confusion left over from some earlier dirty MacPorts installs - I ran `port selfupdate` and those went away. After yet more difficulty with MacPorts, I decided to reconsider building from source. But now, when I use `make`, I get the following series of errors:

```
Maat:wordgrinder-0.5.1 Matt$ make
CC .obj/release/src/c/arch/unix/cursesw/dpy.o
error: unable to open output file '.obj/release/src/c/arch/unix/cursesw/dpy.o': 'Error opening output file '.obj/release/src/c/arch/unix/cursesw/dpy.o': Permission denied'
1 error generated.
make: *** [.obj/release/src/c/arch/unix/cursesw/dpy.o] Error 1
Maat:wordgrinder-0.5.1 Matt$ sudo make
CC .obj/release/src/c/arch/unix/cursesw/dpy.o
src/c/arch/unix/cursesw/dpy.c:164:8: error: use of undeclared identifier 'KEY_EVENT'
                case KEY_EVENT: return "KEY_EVENT";
                     ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [.obj/release/src/c/arch/unix/cursesw/dpy.o] Error 1
Maat:wordgrinder-0.5.1 Matt$
```

First, I have to use `sudo` to get the compiler to access the output file (I don't think I am supposed to have to do that, but not the main issue), and then, when I do, I run into the other one, about the "`use of undeclared identifier 'KEY_EVENT'`". I went over the makefile and the README.Unix several times, but I can't make head nor tail of it. I read in another, unrelated issue with installing WordGrinder on OS X that "building on Mac is a pig," and now I can't help but agree. **What is going wrong, and how can I get WordGrinder to install properly on OS X?**

EDIT 3:
In the end, I wiped my convoluted /usr/local and /opt folders and reorganized a large portion of my filesystem. I installed Homebrew on the clean slate I had created, then installed lua and Homebrew/dupes/ncurses using Homebrew as per the steps Alistair listed in his answer. I then downloaded wordgrinder-0.5.2.1 instead of wordgrinder-0.5.1, because 0.5.2.1 had added Homebrew installation support. No more issues with the backspace key. At this point, `wordgrinder-static` would run, but `wordgrinder` wouldn't (again, as Alistair reported). Installing luafilesystem allowed `wordgrinder` to run, as I predicted in an earlier revision of this answer. I used Homebrew to install luarocks in my Cellar (`brew install luarocks`) and then used luarocks to install luafileystem in my /usr/local/lib/luarocks/rocks directory. `wordgrinder` **now runs perfectly well, with no issues.**

Many thanks to Alistair for all the help. I did learn a lot more than I already did in the process of trying to get this to work, and may be able to take on the rest myself - as I said earlier, I will document my results here as I come up with them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:** As pointed out by Matthew below, the recently released 0.5.2.1 has better support for OS X and brew now, so downloading, extracting wordgrinder-0.5.2.1.tar.bz2 from http://sourceforge.net/projects/wordgrinder/files/wordgrinder/ and running `make` should work. The only dependency you need to install through brew now seems to be lua, so `brew install lua` first if you don't already have lua installed.

**ORIGINAL:** Here's how I got it to work with the previous version...

- Downloaded and extracted the wordgrinder-0.5.1.tar.bz2 file from http://sourceforge.net/projects/wordgrinder/files/wordgrinder/
- Used [brew](http://brew.sh) to install lua: `brew install lua`
- Used brew to install ncurses from homebrew-dupes: `brew install homebrew/dupes/ncurses`
- Made the following modifications to the Makefile. You can download the modified file [here](https://gist.github.com/alistairmcmillan/8fc51eb19b0a19bb16c5).

  - added a definition of z_crc_t
  - modified LDFLAGS so it can find libraries installed through brew
  - modified CPPFLAGS and INCLUDES so it can find include files installed through brew
  - modified ldflags because it is looking for "lua5.2" but the library on OS X is called "lua.5.2"
- Ran `make` which runs okay with these changes. `bin/wordgrinder` crashes right away but `bin/wordgrinder-static` seems to run okay.
- 'sudo make install' fails, so I just copied wordgrinder-static to `/usr/local/bin` and it appears to work successfully there.

Comment: Can you tell us exactly what you are doing? You download the source (I'm assuming into your Downloads folder), extract it, cd into it, type `make` and get permission denied errors?

Comment: That is exactly what I am doing. Sorry, but if you haven't already gathered, I am (relatively, not entirely) new to building and installing from source.

Comment: Sorry, I'm more confused why make isn't working for you than anything else. Where are you putting the source files extracted from wordgrinder-0.5.1.tar.bz2?

Comment: I have a folder on my desktop called temp. In that folder is my copy of wordgrinder-0.5.1.bz2 and a folder called wordgrinder-0.5.1. The last folder I mentioned is where the files extracted from the bz2 are stored and from which I am running make.

Comment: If you go into that wordgrinder-0.5.1 folder in Terminal and type `ls -al` what do the permissions look like? All the folders should be `drwxr-xr-x@` (for the ones that came from the download) or `drwxr-xr-x` (for the ones created by make) and all the files should be `-rw-r--r--@`.

Comment: All the permissions in the folder are in order, as you said. All that running `make` seemed to create was a directory called `.obj` (and miscellaneous contents) with permission 755 and no quarantine flag (as expected.) Besides, there are no problems with permissions when I run `make` with the modified makefile. I am pretty sure that most of the problems I am having are with my wonky/redundant installs of `ncurses` and `lua`. I will have to uninstall a bunch of things then reinstall them properly.

Comment: What do you get if you type `echo $PATH` into a Terminal window?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20674/discussion-between-matthew-brown-and-alistair-mcmillan).

Comment: The modified makefile is now unnecessary - wordgrinder-0.5.2.1 added support for Homebrew installations, and apparently fixed some other issues I was having.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information Alistair and Matthew already provided, I was able to install wordgrinder under both Mavericks and Yosemite through a combination of the two methods he described. In fact, I was able to run wordgrinder, not just wordgrinder-static. Steps to reproduce:

```
brew install lua
brew install Homebrew/dupes/ncurses
brew install luarocks
brew install zlib
luarocks install luafilesystem
```

and then, in the extracted wordgrinder-0.5.2.1 folder.

```
make
sudo make install PREFIX=/usr
```

Alistair and Matthew provided more useful information here than I was able to locate in any number of forums and mailing lists.